# ReactJS: Access parent function from function in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I use a dialog component and pass the onHide function from the parent to the dialog component via props like this:

```
<KundenNeuForm Hider={onHide}></KundenNeuForm>
```

if I call it directly in the render method it works:

```
return (
        <div>
          <Button label="Speichern" onClick={props.Hider} />
        </div>
  );
```

But I want to call a validation function first and then call the parent function from there

```
const Validate=()=> {
  If(Everything validates) {
     //call props.Hider
  }
}
return (
        <div>
          <Button label="Speichern" onClick={Validate} />
        </div>
  );
```

How can I call my parent function from the Validate function?

Comment: yes, you can call it. `props.Hider()`

Comment: I don't know what happened, but it works now. I tried it before and got the error that Hider was not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling props.Hider() actually works